# Export classified raster Class Values from DEM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, export, classification

I've classified an elevation raster into 4 classes. Is there a way to export these class values (0, 1, 2, 3) to a separate raster? I've tried exporting the raster to file, but this just gives the same elevation values.

In other words, I want to replace the pixel values in my DEM with their class values.

Comment: This is what the Con (Spatial Analyst) tool was designed for.

Answer (score 4):

Answered as [How to perform Raster Reclassification in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/how-to-perform-raster-reclassification-in-qgis) indirectly, but I found it can be done either using the [Con (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z00000005000000) tool (@Aaron), or better using the [Reclassify (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) tool.

The "Classify..." button provides the same functionality as in the Layer Symbology dialogue box.

Reclassify creates a new raster based on the classification and Class Values.