# Density slice/Colour slice in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, classification

Can you do Raster Color Slices (like in ENVI) in QGIS?

I.e. Where the histogram can be divided up into discrete units to represent different classes based on the values of the pixels.

Comment: this might help if what you want is create a new file : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/how-to-perform-raster-reclassification-in-qgis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Properties > Styles there is a Color interpolation setting that can be set to Discrete, giving your raster map a more kind of vector polygon look.

Comment: Sorry, I was waiting to see whether there was a better solution of being able to classify using the histogram.