# Extract areas from DEM between 100 meter contours using r.report or similar tools

Tags: qgis, raster, pixel

I'm trying to extract the total area within the same altitude range in a DEM. As example, I'd like to know the total area between 800-900 m asl of a DEM.
Using r.report I've just got this:

[image]

How can I set up the range values instead of a 'random' ranges generated by the gis tool?

I'd like to use this in the same way to calculate slope ranges etc.

Comment: ArcGIS has reclassify tool you can choose equal interval and specify how many intervals you would like. Then you can calculate the areas from pixel counts.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete the answers already suggested, the easiest way to do this is with a combination of `r.reclass` and `r.stats`. Set up a text file with the value ranges you want. Run `r.reclass` on the original DEM to create a reclassed raster. (The advantage here is that the reclass raster is not a new map, just a definition of category values, so it saves space).

Now do `r.stats -a` on the reclass raster. This will output the area for each category value.

Answer (score 1):

The ranges aren't random. I think the default is to set up 255 equal-interval buckets (steps) between the min and max values.

This seems an odd choice, but it is a sensible default for common uses of this tool, for example land cover classifications.

I can't test this at the moment, but i would try the following:-

Use **r.mapcalc** with a formula like this, replacing 'mylayer' with your layer name. Use this to create a new raster.

```
int(mylayer/100)*100.0
```

that will mean range [0, 99.99] maps to 0.0, [100.0-199.9] to 100.0 and so on.

Run **r.report** like you did before. Set the number of buckets using the **nsteps** parameter. For example, if your lowest rounded elevation is 300 and maximum is 700, use 4 bands. [Manual page](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.report.html)

If using QGIS both of these should be available in Processing

Because your min and max values are now multiples of 100, you can use a fixed number of bands. All cells between 800.0 and 899.99 should go in the same band.

There is the **r.reclassify** method, see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/45017/55203) for more info. That needs a text file set up, though, and I think it only works with integers. But it might be better if you want uneven sized ranges.