# QGIS saving raster styles as vectors

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, convert, style

I am using QGIS for analysis of aerial images.

I have used the properties>style menu to create colour-banding for my raster map layer. This created 2 colour bands - but I want to convert these to seperate vectors.

Is it possible to do this - and do I require a plugin?

See below for screen grab:

[image: qgis vector raster conversion]

[image: histogram]

[image: code]

[image: legend]

Comment: Nope,yo need reclassify your raster using the raster calculator ans export the results using raster to vector for create polygons using only your classification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You need first to reclassify your data to get an integer raster
  (see : [Performing Raster Reclassification in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/performing-raster-reclassification-in-qgis))

In your case, reclassify your raster with the formula like below in the Raster Calculator :

```
("Pistford_2_NGRDI_values@1" <= 0.14)*2 + ("Pistford_2_NGRDI_values@1" > 0.14)*1
```

It should look like below :

[image: raster calculator]

- Then you can convert your integer raster to vector polygon :

[image: Polygonize]

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have no programming knowledge - is there a straightforward expression for picking out everything that has a wavelength <-0.14? This is shown as yellow on the image.

Comment: Basically its: >0.14 = 1 and <0.14 = 2 - but I don't know the format to use. Thanks again

Comment: What about values = 0.14 ? I suppose it's <= 0.14 from your printscreen. For your case, I updated my answer with more info

Comment: Ps : the band is specified by @1 or @2. Make sure your have the right band in the formula.

Comment: Brilliant - thaniks for all your help - I'll have a go today and report back

Comment: Despite my best efforts - it seems to just create an empty raster with a white and a black symbol. I basically just want a layer of anything with a frequency less than minus 0.14 (-0.14). I'll post the histogram etc in the main post

Comment: I guess what your missing is just styling. Please check your created raster metadata (in properties) and see what are the min/max values (it should be 1 and 2). Black and white seems good to me, as we wanted to have only 2 values (basically 1 and 2). Make sure you classify your data with exact values. I'll add some screenshot so you can see.