# No cell value in raster file

Tags: raster, terrain

I downloaded a .tif raster file from opentopography.org. It's an Alos (AW3D30
) topography file showing [mountainous terrain in Sweden](https://www.google.at/maps/place/63%C2%B027'55.5%22N+13%C2%B059'10.1%22E/@63.4654074,13.9839393,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m14!1m7!3m6!1s0x466e3b3e92fc9f39:0x676f2cbd402f48f3!2sH%C3%A4llberget!3b1!8m2!3d63.45!4d13.9333333!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d63.4654051!4d13.9861276!5m1!1e4).
On the very right the file contains terrain, and on the left a lake surface.
The lake surfaces have values of -9999 for each cell.

Is there some way to interpolate these -9999 values into values which would somehow correspond to the lake surface elevation? For example, the elevation of the nearby shore/coast is around 300 something meters.
Is there a way to replace all the -9999 values with 300 values in order to get a somewhat acceptable transition from shore/coast to lake surface?

The mentioned file can be downloaded from here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kai6202uewas47j/no_value.tif?dl=0

Comment: For question 2:  Have you tried setting -9999 to NoData
(http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/nodata-in-raster-datasets.htm) and setting any raster cells overlapping or in the vicinity of the shoreline to 300m and then interpolating between existing raster values and shoreline to create a new raster.  You could start by creating point data from your raster and shoreline data after the NoData operation. The link above also explains how to assign NoData to cells.

Comment: If you know the lake surface elevation you can reclassify these from -9999 to 300 (or whatever). You dont mention what GIS software you are using but see for example this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/performing-raster-reclassification-in-qgis

Comment: Thank you for the replies both @ZrSiO4 and @BERA!
BERA can you add a new reply? I can't label your comment as the solving one.