# How to polygonise a large and detailed raster into a single valid polygon with QGIS?

Tags: qgis, r, polygon, dissolve, polygonize

I am doing research on the protected areas of the Amazon rainforest and I need to create a single polygon layer that has all the forested non-protected areas in one attribute row. I have tried using different polygonise functions in QGIS with different dissolve functions and fixing geometries, but I always end up with the same final layer which has invalid geometry.

After polygonising the raster and saving the forested areas, I have a multipolygon layer (with thousands of rows in the attribute table) which looks like what I wish to achieve: 
[image: Multipolygon layer]

However, when I try to dissolve the layer into a single polygon layer (with SAGA Polygon Dissolve (all polygons), but the same happens with GDAL Dissolve), I get these polygons within polygons:

[image: Singlepolygon layer]

*(This is just one area, not the whole layer, showing the areas that appear after trying to dissolve the multipolygon layer)*

I've tried to use "Fix geometries", but that only removed some of the unwanted areas (the fixed image is included here).

I have tried to fix this problem for more than a week now and am running out of options to try.

Edit:
I am running 3.2.0-Bonn on Windows 10. My GDAL/OGR version is 2.2.4 and I use WGS84 as my CRS.

Comment: Any chance you could crop your raster down to something small that illustrates the problem which you could share with us?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking one question per Question. Unfortunately, "Using A or B" questions are considered two questions, since the solutions are very different. Given that your description is about QGIS, I suggest yor remove R, and include exact details about the version(s) of QGIS (and GDAL) in use, and the exact spatial reference and command parameters involved.

Comment: Not sure if it will fix it, but I also had the problem that after I vectorized a rasterimage the created polygons had tons of geometry errors (intersections) and I was not able to process them. The "fix geometry" tools did not work either. What I did to fix it in the end is, that I drew a really small buffer around the polygons. The buffered polygons had no geometry errors. Perhaps it does work for you.

Comment: Can you select manually the little polygons that fill the holes ?

Comment: @Spacedman I extracted a small area of the raster to share. The problem remained with the small area. Here is what I did with this smaller area in more detail: 
1. I clipped the raster using “Clip raster by mask layer” tool. 
2. I used “Polygonize (raster to vector)” tool (GDAL) to get a polygon
3. I selected and saved the forested areas (“DN”=1) 
4. I used “Polygon dissolve (all polygons)” tool (SAGA) to dissolve the polygon layer of the forested areas. 

You can get the files from each step here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ymspybohfwfvmdj/AACVMGnPRF9nUHfixCWgV_vza?dl=0

Comment: I edited the question to only ask one question, thank you @Vince for the tour link and guidance!

Comment: @Volta I cannot manually select the little polygons because they appear after I have used the dissolve function. However, if I use the “Multipart to singleparts” tool, I can select at least most of the little erroneous polygons.

Comment: @gHupf I tried the “Fixed distance buffer“ tool (SAGA) with a buffer distance of 0.000001 (smallest), 1 buffer zone, 5.0 Arc Vertex Distance (*I do not know what this does, I couldn’t find an explanation online*), Dissolve buffers ticked. When I looked at this layer closely. I noticed that although the error polygons were gone, some small holes had for some reason dissolved into the forested polygon area (noticeable if one flips between 4 and 5).  Also, I don’t know if the polygon approach is optimal for me, as I do not want *any* non-forested area to be under the forested polygon.

Comment: `I need to create a single polygon layer that has all the forested non-protected areas in one attribute row.` > what is your final objective with that ? If you need to erase something from another raster, a raster treatment approach may be more effective.

Comment: @gisnside No, I need to take a random sample from the non-protected forested area and I use the polygon layer as the area from which the sample is taken. I use the spsample function in R for sampling. My code requires the polygon layer to have one polygon with one attribute row in order to work... I think I could use the multipolygon layer if I used x = "Polygons", but because these issues have come up I fear the geometry is invalid and there would be errors in the sampling.

Comment: I see. Maybe this could help, it's very similar to what you want to do, except it  uses a grid of square meshes : https://wpqr4.adb.org/servlet/QuickrSupportUtil?type=quickrdownload&key=/LotusQuickr/agstat_ap/Main.nsf/0/FE1A5E7F3280508548257DF2001ED469/$file/06_Sampling%2520Point.pdf

Comment: I added a new part to my answer.

Comment: It looks like the rings in your polygon are being turned into separate polygons, which can happen sometimes when non-core tools (ie SAGA and GDAL). Have you tried dissolving using the built-in QGIS > Vector Geometry > Dissolve tool? You could also try the Merge tool (advanced digitizing toolbar).

Comment: @csk Interesting. I have tried both without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to check if this was a QGIS specific problem and did the same process in ArcGIS on a different computer. I dissolved the multipolygon layer, and ArcGIS did not visualize the errors – even though I was using a copy of the same file. However, when I looked at this dissolved "error free" file in QGIS, the errors reappeared.

I decided to try the sampling to see if the sample points would appear on the error areas or not. I created a new singlepolygon layer in the latest version of QGIS (3.2.3. Bonn) and used Fix geometries tool. I used the fixed layer in the sampling and no samples appeared on the "error" areas (see picture). Besides a visual check, I also reaffirmed this by quantitative means in R.

My best guess is that this was a visual bug in QGIS since ArcGIS did not show these errors in the same file.

[image: Sample points visualized in QGIS: No samples appeared on the "erroroneous" coloured polygon within polygon areas.]

Answer (score 2):

**For your specific question :**

- Reclassify your raster (to avoid further polygon dissolving) to make sure to have only 0/1 values, so that "1" values are the ones your need to convert into polygons (See [Performing Raster Reclassification in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/17712/25139]) if necessary)
- Convert this raster into a polygon with the [r.to.vect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.to.vect.html) GRASS tool, you should get all the raster value converted, cut in polygones with "0" and "1" values, on the raster footprint.
- In the attribute table, delete "0" values, you should only have left "1" values polygons
- Use the "Single to Multipart" tool to restore one polygone multipolygon

**For your final objective :**

Notice : For this part, you don't need one multipolygon.

- To complete your final objective and inspired by [this document](https://wpqr4.adb.org/servlet/QuickrSupportUtil?type=quickrdownload&key=/LotusQuickr/agstat_ap/Main.nsf/0/FE1A5E7F3280508548257DF2001ED469/$file/06_Sampling%2520Point.pdf) , create a mesh or a regular point or polygon grid on your polygon layer boundary. You can use the vector Menu/Research Tools/Create grid tool or with QGIS geoprocessing tools/ Vectero creation tool/regular points
- Select all points or polygons that are within your selected polygon area, invert selection, then delete external features.
- With the vector Menu/Research Tools/Random selection tool, select a number of random interest points.

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by “raster footprint”, this is a new term for me, but I used the default options of the r.to.vect tool to create a polygon layer from the raster. I also assume you meant Multipart to singleparts tool, which I used after deleting the 0 values from the attribute table. However, this did not create one multipolygon layer, I still had separate rows of data. When I dissolved this, the result had the same errors.

Comment: The random sampling you suggested does not work for my purposes, unfortunately.

Comment: Interestingly, as I used Fixed geometries to remove the errors, they were all gone and I had the layer I want, but I am unable to save it, because when I do, the errors reappear in the saved file. Does anyone know why that is?