# How to pixelwise annotation with QGIS

Tags: qgis, image, sentinel-2, image-segmentation, deep-learning

I need to create masks with QGIS of hedgerows for satellite images (raster) segmentation.

I tried with the SCP plugin but I can't use growing algorithm because I only want to keep hedgerows, not forests.

So how can I pixel-wise annotate my raster with QGIS ? Any plugin ?

Do you think there is a semi-supervised technique, better than pixel-wise manual annotation that can solve my problem ?

Comment: In order to identify hedgerows, you need to figure out what distinguishes a forest from a hedgerow. Then you can refine the SCP growing algorithm results. If hedgerows are always next to roads, buffer a road layer and clip the raster to the road buffer. If hedgerows are always long and skinny, polygonize the raster, filter the polygons based on length to width ratio, and use that to clip the raster.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and sry for my late one : when I rasterize my image, it gives me a lot of polygones , sometimes 1 for each pixel. How can make them larger based on a "similiraty threshold" for example ?

Comment: That's called "reclassification." This Q&A describes how to reclassify a raster: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/performing-raster-reclassification-in-qgis