# Highlighting terrain only between defined elevation range

Tags: polygon, layers, elevation

I am trying to highlight terrain between two elevations in order to highlight where certain plants could be found. For example if a plant in found in a certain valley between 600-1200m, I'd like to be able to make a polygon around the valley and then highlight the terrain in a false color that is between the two elevations to show where it could theoretically be found. Above and below these elevations would transparent. The map so far consists of a satellite image layer and a DEM layer.

How can I accomplish the goal?

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: It sounds like you want 3 values in your output: too low, just high enough and way too high, is this the case? Or is it that you want only the *good part* and the rest NoData? Or is it that you want a polygon feature class of the nominated elevation range? If you're using open source software have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/performing-raster-reclassification-in-qgis if not you will need to specify which software you have available as @ahmadhanb asked.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  Here it is expected that you will tell us not just what you want to do but also what you have researched and preferably tried to do before getting stuck and posting.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using QGIS, and all you want is the highlighting, you can use the layer styling on your DEM layer to very easily achieve your highlighting. See screenshot below:

- set Render Type to Singleband pseudocolor
- set Mode to Quantile, and delete entries until you get three bands
- set the value field of the first two bands to the top and bottom numbers of your range (I've used 400-600m since that was appropriate to my data)
- set the styling on the first and last band to have opacity of 0%

[image: QGIS layer styling]

[image: The results]