# I have a satellite image. I want to sample all the trees and vectorize them at once

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, land-cover, land-classification, land-use

I have a satellite imagery. I want to vectorize all the trees at once by color sampling. How to do it?

I used Photoshop to sample the all the various color ranges of trees [Green] to distinguish between trees and built-up area. Can I use this technique as the Photoshop converted the trees in satellite image in one colour. As you can see in this image I sampled all the trees and converted to black colour to distinguish between trees and built-up area. Now can I select this color from this image and convert it to a VECTOR for Land use and Land cover map in QGIS.

[image: Image from photoshop]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.  You have a few options.

1. If you have a new raster layer in which all of the trees are now colored black you could use a reclassify tool to produce a new raster such that all of the trees have a value of 1 and all of the non-tree pixels have a value of 0.  Then [polygonize that result](https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/complete_analysis/raster_to_vector.html).  [See this link for more help on reclassifying options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17712/performing-raster-reclassification-in-qgis).
2. Have a look at the [semi-automatic classification plugin in](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/).  This approach would save you a Photoshop processing step in the first place and likely retained any spatial information that was contained in the original data.   https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/p/semi-automatic-classification-plugin.html

Comment: Yea. Thanks for the help. I found a detailed Tutorial for this Land Classification with SCP Plugin. This video should help the newbies like me 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKNS-wsc7lo

Comment: Hey I need some help. I have done entire experiment/calssification with SCP Plugin but after completing the entire classification I could not able to see classification tab in SCP Dock. Open the link of image of SCP Dock 

https://imgur.com/0jUoVau